# java jvm maximum and minimum heap options

Tags: java, memory-management

Two jvm options that we can provide -Xms and -Xmx which are minimum and maximum heap size for jvm respectively. In a lot of applications, I have noticed both these values to be same. Is there a specific or good reason why developers chose to have both minimum and maximum possible heap to be same?

Thanks

Comment: So you can specify exactly how much memory it uses? Seems pretty self explanatory.

Comment: -Xms is "initial java heap size" and not minimum heap size

Comment: It takes the JVM time to expand memory. It can cause unnecessary system wide GC, while the JVM works out it needs to allocate more memory. In the case of a server, this is unacceptable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when we set Xmx and Xms equal size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087153/what-happens-when-we-set-xmx-and-xms-equal-size)

Answer (score -1):

One answer could be to avoid memory fragmentation, so the vm would start already with the max allowed allocating size

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: Not setting the Xmx doesn't result in fragmentation.